# Ему пришлось спрятаться - иначе они его заметили бы.

Tags: синтаксис

> Ему пришлось спрятаться – **иначе они его заметили бы**.

Если я понимаю правильно, "иначе" = "в противном случае". Можно сказать, что это два простых предложения, которые можно было бы связать через запятую? 
Спасибо.

Comment: и тогда бы; или

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, вполне. Иначе = а то,в противном случае.

Ему пришлось спрятаться, иначе они его заметили бы.

Comment: большое спасибо! скажите, пожалуиста, "иначе" это наречие или союз? и если это союз, можно считать, что это противительныи' союз?

Comment: @ Anonym, в данном случае союз. Но может быть и наречием. ИНАЧЕ. I. нареч. ***Иным способом, иным образом, не так; по-иному, по-другому***. И. поступить нельзя. С этой девушкой он держался и., чем с другими.

Answer (score 1):

**Можно ли сказать, что это два простых предложения, которые можно было бы связать через запятую?**

Строго говоря, **в грамматике нет такого понятия**, так как простые предложения входят в состав сложного предложения (сложносочиненного ССП, сложноподчиненного СПП или бессоюзного сложного БСП), да и запятые могут стоят в любом из них.

Наречие "иначе" выступает в роли союза: **ИНАЧЕ** II. в зн. союза. Разг. **В противном случае, а то**. Беги, иначе опоздаешь.

Обычно такой тип предложения рассматривается **как ССП с разделительными союзами ИЛИ, А ТО, А НЕ ТО.** Сюда же относятся разговорные союзы "иначе, в противном случае."

Но это особый подвид  сложного предложения (ССП) со **значением альтернативной мотивации** (в нем рассматривается связь двух ситуаций, одна из которых нежелательна). Фактически здесь присутствует **и значение причины** (почему надо спрятаться), **и значение условия** (что будет, если не спрячешься). Поэтому эти предложения по значению близки с СПП, но по форме относятся с ССП с разделительными союзами.